# Has anyone successfully converted AWS api from Xcode 7 Swift 2.x to Xcode 8 Swift 3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, swift3, xcode8

The title says it all. Has anyone successfully converted AWS api from Xcode 7 Swift 2.x to Xcode 8 Swift 3? I'm trying to set up access to DynamoDB using MobileHub. Works great in Xcode 7 but no so well when converted.